# How to detect users that downvote all other answers

Tags: discussion, downvotes, voting

There is this question: [Allow opening a file with open() only in one process, in c unix programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29733499/allow-opening-a-file-with-open-only-in-one-process-in-c-unix-programming/29733648#29733658) on which all 4 answers are related to the `flock() function, however suddenly all but one answer got downvoted (without comments), and the poster added at the middle some code not related to the question.

I'm thus a little suspicious on the 3 downvotes, it looks like the answerer tried to make the other answers less visible. So my question is - is there a way to find out if the same user downvoted the answers?

Comment: The guy doesn't even have 125 rep, so he can't downVote

Comment: His answer got an up-vote, could it be that the second user voted on all answers?

Comment: @Cristik: that, or maybe their answer is just better?

Comment: Seems much more plausible that a user thought the one answer was very detailed and all the others were not as detailed (in fact I'm deleting one of them because it's not an answer).

Comment: @MartijnPieters: it might be that the answer is better, however my suspicions were related to the downvotes and the garbage inside the upvoted answer. I revisited that answer and it looks like an editor added the completely irrelevant parts of the answer (http://stackoverflow.com/posts/29733658/revisions).

Comment: Now that I see the original answer it makes sense for someone who visited the question before the edits to have upvoted/downvoted. So another question: can a revision be flagged? :)

Comment: @animuson Did you read the upvoted answer though? It reads like someone edited and pasted a question in the middle of it. I'm considering a rollback.

Comment: @mikez agreed, this edit was nonsense, I rolled it back.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski Yup, obviously a copy paste error from an edit on [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29732935/why-garbage-value-in-union-integer)

Comment: Only jeff and joel can see whats going on inside,

Comment: @Starkeen That is incorrect; SE has [about a dozen of community managers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/99341/259867) with access to votes, not counting an unspecified number of developers with such access.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Most of us cannot determine when a user who posts an answer *also* downvotes all the other answers on the question.** Even if you can see that their answer has not been downvoted whereas all others have, you cannot be *certain* that the author of the one answer that did not get downvoted is the person who downvoted the other answers.

Now, it would be easy for the SE devs to implement an algorithm that automatically raises a flag when it so happens that a user who has answered a question has also downvoted all the other answers. The problem though is how the moderators should interpret the flag. Most of us would agree that downvoting answers *merely* to make one's own answer stand out is not a valid use of voting. However, it is perfectly legitimate for someone who answers an question to downvote other answers if they find the other answers to be useless or harmful, seeing as these are reasons to downvote answers. (If such voting were not allowed it would be blocked by the site.) **The problem is distinguishing cases when someone is tactically downvoting from cases when someone is just applying their quality standards.** Let me give an example. Some people will, as a matter of principle, downvote any answer that references sites that they consider to be bad references. A famous example is w3schools.com. Some people hold that sending readers to that site is actively harmful. Let's suppose Alice is one such user. She runs into a question where there are 2 answers already, which both reference a bad site. So she downvotes them and adds her own answer, which explains more thoroughly than the other answers and references a site she considers more reputable. It might appear to someone who received an automatically generated flag that she engaged in strategic voting but really she was just applying the same standards she applies to all answers she runs into.

Such flag could also potentially harm vote anonymity. Currently, only some SE employees are able to see who voted on what. An automatically generated flag which would be visible only to SE employees would not harm anonymity but I'm pretty sure the flag volume would overwhelm them. If the flag is made visible to moderators (who do not happen to also be SE employees), then this harms vote anonymity because it would provide moderators with information they do not currently have.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation, my  suspicions were related not only to the downvotes,  but to the long irrelevant text from the middle of the answer (that I found out later that was mistakenly added by someone who edited that answer). It's clear to me now that there's no point in trying to hunt such cases.